# How do I echo posted data from javascript in the php side for development?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using Symfony 5 and I'm posting data from javascript using axios to the php server side. For development purpose, I want the posted data to be displayed on the page so I can better structure and see them.

js file

```
const onSubmit = () => {
    axios.post('mystuff/post', data)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

php file

```
/**
 * @Route("/mystuff/post")
 */
public function postData(Request $request)
{
    $post_data = $request->getContent();
    return new JsonResponse($post_data)
}
```

The above codes works by throwing the data back to the js side and console logging it out, but it is so hard to really see them in the console. So I want something like echoing the data in the controller and displaying them right on the page. How can I do this?

Comment: Exactly the same way you display any other variable data on your website. Just create an element with a unique id and set innerText: `document.getElementById("your-element").innerText = response.data;`

Comment: `.then(response => {
        document.getElementById("your-element").innerText = response.data;
    })` or similar

Comment: I got the error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null` doing this

Comment: Oh I figured the problem, I was pointing to a class instead of id. The response data is displaying on the page successfully. But still it's just a bunch of strings and hard to read, how do I format it like with `<pre></pre>` in php?

Comment: `const el = document.createElement("pre");el.textContent = response.data;document.body.appendChild(el);  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a react component [react-json-pretty](https://github.com/chenckang/react-json-pretty) that do just that. I just pass in the json response string and it will format it in hierarchy order.

js file

```
import JSONPretty from 'react-json-pretty';

const App = () => {
    const [jsonString, setjsonString] = useState("");

    const onSubmit = () => {
        axios.post('mystuff/post', data)
        .then(response => {
            setjsonString(response.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

    return(
        <>
            <JSONPretty id="json-pretty" data={jsonString}></JSONPretty>
            <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </>
    )

}
```